# Will instantiating a lot of variables (string, int, etc.) consume a lot of memory?

Tags: c#

I've been thinking of making my code *more readable*. I have *a lot of foreach and for loops* since I handle lots of DataTables in my code.

Is it okay if I instantiate column names that I will use inside loops? Or will it consume too much memory? For example:

```
DataTable fooTable = new DataTable();

foreach(DataRow dr in fooTable.Rows)
{
   string nameColumn = dr.Field<string>("NAME")
   Console.WriteLine(nameColumn)
}
```

vs.

```
DataTable fooTable = new DataTable();

foreach(DataRow dr in fooTable.Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine(dr.Field<string>("NAME"))
}
```

Comment: Memory is allocated when you *instantiate* an object, not when you *reference* it. Thus no matter how many references to the same instance you have, the memory won´t increase (apart from the really low memory-consumption of 4bytes (???) for the reference itself).

Comment: So is it advisable if I instantiate a lot of objects, for the purpose of having a clearer and more readable code?

Comment: Don't guess with memory performance. Set (realistic) goals, write *simple, easy to read code*, then *measure*. If it meets your goals, great, move on. Admittedly, it takes some experience to know what realistic goals are, but don't try to learn *anything* performance related by memorizing rote rules.

Comment: I guess I'll worry about memory and performance later. For now, I'll stick with what you've advised and make the code more readable, even if I end up using lots of variables.

Comment: Rule number one of optimization: you're usually wrong about where you think performance problems might be. Point in case: `DataTable` is a very inefficient class in terms of memory use, compared to containers of strongly-typed objects. If memory use truly was an issue, that would likely be worth looking at way sooner than any of your variables. (Rule zero also applies here: you're usually wrong about the need to optimize in the first place, and you're *always* wrong if you haven't measured anything yet.)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely (certainly in debug mode) that there's an unnamed local variable used to store the result of `dr.Field<string>("Name")` in the version where you don't name a variable.

And even then, the variable exists once in this method. You don't get a new variable *each time through the loop*.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is allocated when you *instantiate* an object, not when you *reference* it. Thus no matter how many references to the same instance you have, the memory won´t increase.

This means the following two lines are identical considering their memory-footprint:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

and

```
Console.WrileLine(new MyClass());
```

in both cases there´s exactly *one single* instance of your class, not two. Thus the memory-consumoption is exactly that for one instance of the class (plus some small amount for the references theirselves, on a 32bit machine that´s 4bytes, on 64bit 8byte).

In your case memory is allocated when calling `dr.Field<string>("NAME")`. However in your first code the object is referenced, thus it may be garbage-collected some nano-seconds later (when the loop is on the next iteration).

Having said this it´s very unlikely that your memory increases much (if at all) when you have a million references all referencing the exact same object.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a temporary variable like `nameColumn` whenever you are in this kind of situation.

Each time you call `dr.Field<string>("NAME")`, the runtime has to construct an iterator and execute a string matching algorithm on a collection of objects just to find the right field to access. The amount of overhead caused by accessing the `Field` method far exceeds whatever impact may be caused by the temporary variable.

So if you ever plan to use `nameColumn` in more than one place, the variable is what you need. Even if you don't re-use it, putting it in at the beginning is not a bad practice.

Adding the variable is not likely to have any negative impact. The compiler may even end up generating the same IL anyway.